# Running Java module from command line breaks when I reverse argument order

Tags: java, module, command-line-arguments, java-9

I can run a Java module from the command line without issues as follows:

```
java -p "dir/with/module1;dir/with/module2" -m my.module.name
//runs fine
```

However, when I reverse the arguments, putting -m (--module) before -p (--module-path), it doesn't work and results in the following error:

```
java -m my.module.name -p "dir/with/module1;dir/with/module2"
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module my.module.name not found
```

Is this expected behavior? Can someone confirm whether the order of the -p and -m arguments matters?

Here's my Java version for reference:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.12.7.1 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.12.7.1 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Official documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html)

> To launch the main class in a module:
> `java [options] -m module[/mainclass] [args...]`

`-p` is an option that must come before `-m`

Comment: Or, in other words, everything after the `-m module[/mainclass]` argument is passed to the `main` method in the string array argument, without interpretation.